# Browsable API becomes unreadable when too many child relations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I limit the number of child relations listed in the HyperlinkedModelSerializer's HyperlinkedRelatedField? When there's hundreads or thousands of child relations, the whole page becomes very quickly unreadable and slow. The page-size itself is not the problem, but how many child relations are visible.

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    bars = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, view_name='bar-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name="bars", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

In the browsable API: /api/v1/foos/

```
{
    "count": 6,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/foos/1/",
            "name": "Something"
            "bars": [
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/3/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/4/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/5/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/6/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/7/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/8/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/9/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/10/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/11/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/12/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bars/13/",
                .....
```

As you can see this list becomes very long very quickly. Would be good to cut it to max five or so.
For the Form input-fields there HTML_SELECT_CUTOFF but I believe there's nothing similar to read_only=True fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following: instead of using the relation directly, use a property to get only some of the children:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # ...
    @property    
    def bars_top(self):
        items_to_show = 5
        return self.bars.all()[:items_to_show]


class FooSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    bars_top = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, view_name='bar-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('id', 'bars_top')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate it!  However, I get this: `...models.py", line 27, in bars_top
    return self.bars[:items_to_show]
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix that error, try again.

Comment: Awesome!   Thanks a bunch!